# Why does this Sql Statement (with 2 table joins) takes 5 mins to complete?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

#### Updates : 3 updates added below

The following sql statement takes 5 mins to complete. I. Just. Don't. Get. It :(
First table has 6861534 rows in it. Second table has a little bit less .. and third table (which contains 4 GEOGRAPHY FIELDS) has the same as the first.

Those `GEOGRAPHY` fields in the 3rd table .. they shouldn't be messin' with the sql statement ... should it? Could it be because the table is so large (due to the `GEOGRAPHY` fields) that it has huge page sizes or something .. thus destroying the table scan a COUNT does?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[Locations] a
    inner join [dbo].[MyUSALocations] b on a.LocationId = b.LocationId
    inner join [dbo].[GeographyBoundaries] c on a.locationid = c.LocationId
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Update

As requested, here's some more info about the GeographyBoundaries table...
[image]

```
/****** Object:  Index [PK_GeographyBoundaries]    Script Date: 11/16/2010 12:42:36 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[GeographyBoundaries] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_GeographyBoundaries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LocationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

#### Update #2 - After adding the Non-Clustered Index

After adding the non-clustered index, it's now dropped down to 4 seconds! Which is awesome. But **why** ?

[image]

What Zee Frak?

#### Update 3 - even more interesting and confusing info!

Now, when i just do ONE join and force the INDEX .. it goes back to 5 mins. I did this to

- Make sure the MyUSALocations table wasn't screwing things around with the Joins.
- Make sure the PK is doing weird things.

.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[Locations] a 
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[GeographyBoundaries] c
            WITH (INDEX(PK_GeographyBoundaries)) ON a.locationid = c.LocationId
```

Comment: Are all of the LocationId fields ints? varchar(5000)? other?

Comment: is the index on GeographyBoundaries physically located on the same filegroup as the table data?

Comment: @Tahbaza : yes, all the Id's are INT's. This is all in ONE filegroup, or whatever the default standard is. I've not made any tweaks to a default *Create New DB*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ain't right.

I have two possibilities:

1) Statistics is out of date on the tables. Rebuild indexes and update stats.

2) As you said, Geography table records are big spanning many pages (not that one record spanning multiple pages since it can't but the record is close to the 8K mark). In this case, funny enough, creating another non-clustered  index on the clustered index might help.

**UPDATE**

I am pleased that it has worked. Now some explanation.

First of all, if something is not really right and execution plan looks weird, always looks at statistics and rebuild indexes.

Creating a non-clustered index for the clustered index usually should not provide any benefit but when the table has many records and the record is close to its 8K limit, it is helpful. As you know, SQL when it goes to the disk to load a record, it loads an 8K page. In a similar way going to indexes it will load an 8K page. Now with index being a 4-byte integer this means loading ID for 2000 records while it is going to load handful records if it uses clustered index (bear in mind all we need is the ID for the JOIN bit). Now with this being a binary search, I don't expect it to hugely help only a bit. So perhaps something else is not quite right, but difficult to guess not having seen the system.

Comment: ok, i've updated the statistics which took 32 seconds. Now i'm running the query again ... it's upto 1 minute so far and still going .. so i'm not sure if that has helped (much).

Comment: DUDE! WTFFFFFFFFFF!!!!!!!!!!!  By adding a new non-clustered index it's now 4 seconds long (which is what i expect). You got it! Er... but why?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure without seeing some data, but 97% of your cost is your clustered index scan on the GeographyBonudaries table. Is the LocationID the primary key of your GeographyBoundaries table?

You could try creating a new table with just the locationID in it and join with it instead of the GeographyBoundaries table to see if the geography fields are your culprate.  Just make sure you set up all of your indexes the same to make sure you are comparing apples to apples.  I would guess that those fields are slowing you down.

If that does speed things up, and getting a count is something you need to do fairly often, consider keeping this new table and just refreshing it periodically, depending on how often the data is updated and how accurate you need the count to be at any given point in time.

Just out of curiosity, what is the definition for your PK_GeographyBoundaries?

Comment: i've updated the initial post to include some more info about the GeographyBoundaires table, as requested.

Comment: Ahh OK. The SQL supplied just had count(*)!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that most of the work is I/O.  The query plan seems to indicate high I/O cost relative to CPU cost.  For example, on PK_GeographyBoundries the Estimated CPU cost is about 7.5 and the Estimated I/O cost is about 1730, which is a big percentage of the Estimated Operator Cost.

The statistics may be out of date, but it doesn't seem that they would be too helpful.  It has to scan the whole table anyways.  It may benefit from a scan on a non-clustered index, if it's stored on fewer pages, but you have a lot of I/O no matter what.  And, the best index is LocationID, which is clustered on both tables.  You got the best index already.

If it's important to improve performance, then you have to look at ways to speed the physical I/O.

I'm not sure if the geography columns are affecting the performance.  The query plan shows that the row sizes are small (11 bytes each).

Comment: in summary, my HD sucks and i should look at upgrading?

Comment: @Pure Krome:  It may not be that you have a sucky HD.  To improve I/O performance you can do two things:  1) do less I/O or 2) do the I/O faster.  It appears that your Update 2 demonstrates #1.  The reason the nonclustered index does less I/O is that it takes less space (locationID only, no geography).  It takes less time to scan fewer pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well you dont need to involve the "locations" table, a straight join between the USA_Loacations and Geographic boundries will siffice. The optimiser has already noticed this and factored out the loacations table, but, it may pick a better join strategy if you join them directly.

Comment: I need to join to the *parent* Locations table because it has a field (NAME NVARCHAR(100)) in there, which I require.