# SQL Query get a lot of timeouts

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, timeout

I have a large database table (SQL Server 2008) where i have all my forum messages being stored (The table currently have more than 4.5 million entries).

this is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ForumMessage](
    [MessageId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [ForumId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MemberId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [Body] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Posted] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Confirmed] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReplyToMessage] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalAnswers] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AvgRateing] [decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TotalRated] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReadCounter] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_GroupMessage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MessageId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

One issue that i see keep coming back is that when i'm running my stored procedure that select a message and all its replies, i get sometime time-outs errors from the SQL server.

This is my stored procedure:

```
select fm1.[MessageId]
      ,fm1.[ForumId]
      ,fm1.[MemberId]
      ,fm1.[Type]
      ,fm1.[Status]
      ,fm1.[Subject]
    ,fm1.[Body]
      ,fm1.[Posted]
      ,fm1.[Confirmed]
      ,fm1.[ReplyToMessage]
      ,fm1.[TotalAnswers]
      ,fm1.[AvgRateing]
      ,fm1.[TotalRated]
      ,fm1.[ReadCounter],
     Member.NickName AS MemberNickName, Forum.Name as ForumName
from ForumMessage fm1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Member ON fm1.MemberId = Member.MemberId INNER JOIN
                Forum On fm1.ForumId = Forum.ForumId
where MessageId = @MessageId or ReplyToMessage=@MessageId
order by MessageId
```

the error that i get look like this: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding"

I was looking on the execution plan, and the only this that look suspicious is that is see that the query has a cost of about 75%-87% (it varies) on the key lookup in the forummessage table (which i don't understand why, because i set it up as clustered, so i was hoping it will be much more efficient). I was always under that assumption that when you search on clustered index, the query should be very efficient.

Is there anyone has any idea how i can improve this issue and this query to get a message and its replies?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include the execution plan in your question?

Comment: Why the loeft join, don;t all messages have to be from memebers?

Answer (score 0):

**Two** suggestions come to my mind:

- Remove the **ugly** `OR` and add a `UNION` for the condition (CODE BELOW)
- You must have a **non-clustered index** on `ReplyToMessage`

As a last resort, create a non-clustered index and put `MessageId` AND `ReplyToMessage` in there. (See my answer to another question here [Why does this Sql Statement (with 2 table joins) takes 5 mins to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190128/why-does-this-sql-statement-with-2-table-joins-takes-5-mins-to-complete/4190216#4190216))

---

## CODE:

```
select fm1.[MessageId]
      ,fm1.[ForumId]
      ,fm1.[MemberId]
      ,fm1.[Type]
      ,fm1.[Status]
      ,fm1.[Subject]
    ,fm1.[Body]
      ,fm1.[Posted]
      ,fm1.[Confirmed]
      ,fm1.[ReplyToMessage]
      ,fm1.[TotalAnswers]
      ,fm1.[AvgRateing]
      ,fm1.[TotalRated]
      ,fm1.[ReadCounter],
     Member.NickName AS MemberNickName, Forum.Name as ForumName
from ForumMessage fm1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Member ON fm1.MemberId = Member.MemberId INNER JOIN
                Forum On fm1.ForumId = Forum.ForumId
where MessageId = @MessageId
UNION
select fm1.[MessageId]
      ,fm1.[ForumId]
      ,fm1.[MemberId]
      ,fm1.[Type]
      ,fm1.[Status]
      ,fm1.[Subject]
    ,fm1.[Body]
      ,fm1.[Posted]
      ,fm1.[Confirmed]
      ,fm1.[ReplyToMessage]
      ,fm1.[TotalAnswers]
      ,fm1.[AvgRateing]
      ,fm1.[TotalRated]
      ,fm1.[ReadCounter],
     Member.NickName AS MemberNickName, Forum.Name as ForumName
from ForumMessage fm1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      Member ON fm1.MemberId = Member.MemberId INNER JOIN
                Forum On fm1.ForumId = Forum.ForumId
where MessageId = @MessageId
order by MessageId
```

Comment: why is the OR clause so "ugly"

Comment: Why you found 'OR' ugly? As for me pretty well approach, I would say standart, am I wrong? Realy interesting, I always doing the same 'OR' for such simple constraints. BTW, your query will perform table scan twice obviously because of two SELECT!

Comment: i was actually had the union before that the footprint was even worse. are you sure the union would be better here?

Comment: i'm also getting (when using the union): 'The text data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable'

Comment: **Avoid `OR` like a plague!** There are limited cases where we have to use it and there are other cases when using `OR` is computationally acceptable, but **generally try avoiding it**.

Comment: @OrA do you have a non-clustered index on `ReplyMessage`?

Comment: @Aliostad: the @op's query is one of the limited cases when using `OR` is fine.

Comment: @Quassnoi I agree although I would have to run it to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are doing `ORDER BY MessageId`, is it so necessary ordering?

Try to refactory your `SELECT` to `SELECT FROM Forum` and than joining the `Member`, and finally `LEFT JOIN ForumMessage`. So order tables from small to large

Comment: yes, i must return them in the right order to make sure that the data is parsed correctly.

Comment: I just wondering how you are using a message id, I believe any logic should NOT reffer this Id

Answer (score 0):

depending on the version of MS SQL Server you're running you could also try recreating the table utilizing partitioned tables to enhance the `SELECT` performance.

Comment: if i add partitions, would this impact the performance of retrieval old messages?

Comment: it shouldn't, but it really determines on your partitioning scheme. Remember that you'll need to rebuild that table. If you look at the documentation from MSDN, I believe they show dropping any constraints on the table, renaming the table, creating the new partitioned table, then moving the data over, then recreating the constraints, then finally dropping the old table.

Answer (score 0):

Create an index on `ReplyToMessage`:

```
CREATE INDEX
        IX_ForumMessage_ReplyToMessage
ON      ForumMessage (ReplyToMessage)
```

This will most probably result in two index seeks (over the `PRIMARY KEY` on `MessageId` and over the index on `ReplyToMessage`) contatenated with a merge or hash concatenation, rather than a full table scan which you are having now.

Comment: @OrA: this is not obvious from your script. Please post the query plan: run `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` then run your query in the same session.

Comment: i was actually running your script and for whatever reason, its took the 87% down to 14%!!! that much better! should i try to take it even lower or that is a "respectable" number?

Comment: Also, now its shows me that the clustered index scan on the Member table (which have clustered index on the MemberId column, which its also identity), takes 37%, is there anyway to improve that too?

Comment: @ora: could we please start with posting the query plan? My first comment explains how to do that.